# Is there a closed form for $\int_0^\infty\frac{\tanh^3(x)}{x^2}dx$?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration, riemann-zeta-function, closed-form-expressions

For $n\geqslant m>1$, the integral $$I_{n,m}:=\int\limits_0^\infty\dfrac{\tanh^n(x)}{x^m}dx$$ converges. If $m$ and $n$ are both even or both odd, [we can use the residue theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1583085)  to easily evaluate it in terms of odd zeta values, since the integrand then is a nice even function. For example, defining $e_k:=(2^k-1)\dfrac{\zeta(k) }{\pi^{k-1}}$, we have

$$ \begin{align}
I_{2,2}&=  2e_3  \\ \\
I_{4,2}&= \dfrac83e_3-4e_5 \\ \\
I_{4,4}&= -\dfrac{16}{3}e_5+20e_7  \\ \\
I_{6,2}&=\dfrac{46}{15}e_3-8e_5+6e_7 \\ \\
I_{6,4}&=-\dfrac{92}{15}e_5+40e_7-56e_9  \\ \\
I_{6,6}&=\dfrac{46}{5}e_7-112e_9+252e_{11}  \\ \\
I_{3,3}&= -e_3+6e_5  \\ \\
I_{5,3}&= -e_3+10e_5-15e_7  \\  \\
I_{5,5}&=  e_5-25e_7 +70e_9 \\  \\
&etc.
\end{align}$$

But:

> Is there a closed form for $I_{3,2}=\int\limits_0^\infty\dfrac{\tanh^3(x)}{x^2}dx$?

I am not sure at all whether nospoon's method used [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1584566) or one of the other *ad hoc* approaches can be generalized to tackle this.
If the answer is positive, there might be chances that $I_{\frac32,\frac32}$ and the like also have closed forms.

Comment: I don't know whether to hope that we do, or that we don't, find an integration technique called "nospoon's method" in future calculus textbooks.

Comment: A worth noticing feature of your expressions of the considered integrals in terms of the $e_{i}$ is that they're linear, so maybe using a wise mix of integration techniques and linear algebra could lead to something interesting.

Comment: $I_{3,2} \approx 1.154785313323$ is not recognized by the ISC ... isc.carma.newcatle.edu.au

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Yes I know but wow, that "really means nothing". Note that the ISC doesn't even find $1.1274284420316\approx I_{3,3}$ :-(

Comment: You can apply the contour integral method to the equivalent integral $\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint \frac{\operatorname{tahn}^3 z}{z^2} \log(-z) \, dz$, where the contour clockwise tightly encircles the positive real axis.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine But as far as I see, there are no poles inside that contour.

Comment: @Wolfgang, the trick is to start with that contour (which obviously gives the correct answer) and then deform it so that it encircles only poles. You can see a related example in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/96227).

Comment: Do you have a general formula for $I_{2n,2}$?

Comment: @PietroMajer No... it ends with $(-1)^{n+1}\,2n\,e_{2n+1}$, but the coefficients of $e_3$ for $n=3,...,8$ are $46/15,352/105,1126/315=3378/9!!,13016/3465=39048/11!!,...$ having in their numerators biggest prime factors $23,11,563,1627,88069,1423$. This does *not* look very promising.

Comment: @Wolfgang The coefficient of $e_3$ for each $I_{2n,2}$ seems to be $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{2}{2k-1}$. See also https://oeis.org/A074599. I am optimistic similar forms could be found for the other $e_k$ coefficients. Would you be so kind to share in a comment the $e_k$ sequences for $I_{8,2}$,$I_{10,2}$ and $I_{12,2}$ like in your OP?

Comment: @Agno 

$I_{8,2} =\frac1{ 105}( 352 e_3- 1232 e_5+ 1680 e_7- 840 e_9)   

         

$ $I_{10,2} =\frac1{ 945}( 3378 e_3- 14360 e_5+ 27090 e_7- 25200 e_9+ 9450 e_{11})

         

$ $I_{12,2}=\frac1{ 51975}( 195240 e_3- 957308 e_5+ 2244000 e_7- 2938320 e_9+ 2079000 e_{11}- 623700 e_{13}

$ $I_{14,2}=\frac1{ 675675}( 2642070 e_3- 14482832 e_5+ 39859820 e_7- 65745680 e_9+ 66216150 e_{11}- 37837800 e_{13}+9459450 e_{15} )$

Comment: and  $I_{16,2}=\frac1{ 70945875}( 286876800 e_3- 1721992128 e_5+ 5375115200 e_7- 10526195680 e_9+ 13477464000  e_{11}
 -11048637600 e_{13} + 5297292000 e_{15}-1135134000 e_{17} )$ $ \qquad \ $ It didn't occur to me to look up the numerators in the oeis :)

Comment: Thanks for your swift response! It is really nice playing with these formulae.

Comment: @Agno You are welcome. I like your optimism, and I already start sharing it :) Hoping you'll find something. Big prime factors are no threat indeed, and BTW the coefs from the right seem to be polynomial: $[e_{2n-1}]I_{2n,2}=\frac43n(n-1)$, $[e_{2n-3}]I_{2n,2}=-\frac2{45}n(n-2)(10n-7)$, $[e_{2n-5}]I_{2n,2}=\frac2{2835}n(n-3)(70n^2-147n+62)$ etc.

Comment: @Wolfgang. I believe I have found a clue. When you expand all formulae (i.e. no brackets left) and then divide each coefficient of $e_k$ by $2n$, then you exactly get the Sloane's series (to be read as a triangle) https://oeis.org/A141904 (numerator) and https://oeis.org/A142048 (denominator). These are related to the Taylor expansion of $\arctan(1)$, but unfortunately no easy closed form is mentioned there. I keep searching!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60134/discussion-between-wolfgang-and-agno).

Comment: @user75829 Interesting. Never heard of gd(x) before! But as far as I see, it  is essentially just notation?

Comment: for the record: some great answers for $I_{2,2}$ are [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1582943/integral-int-0-infty-frac-tanh2xx2dx)

Comment: @Wolfgang I have some questions about this problem I'd like to ask you, is there a way I could contact you?

Comment: @MaxMuller sure but why not here?

Comment: @Wolfgang It's tangentially related to this problem and it's more of a research proposal, though perhaps you have an answer at hand already. I'm looking for a family of integrals that amounts to $\sum_{i=1}^{k} \left[ {k \atop i} \right] \zeta(i+1) $ for a given power $k$ of a function. Based on <a href="https://mathoverflow.net/questions/231964/how-to-prove-that-int-0-infty-frac-textarcsinhnxxmdx-is-a-rational?rq=1">this</a> question you asked earlier, it seems that $(\frac{\text{arcsinh}(x)}{x})^{k} $ might come close. Perhaps you could find a function that would actually answer the question

Comment: @Wolfgang This is the question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/409560/is-there-any-literature-on-sum-i-1k-left-k-atop-i-right-zetai1

Comment: @MaxMuller That is a nice question, I wasn't aware of it. As you say, the $(\frac{\text{arcsinh}(x)}{x})^{k}$ comes close, but the polynomials for that are $\prod_{j=-k}^k(x-j)$ and $\prod_{j=1-k}^k(x-(j+\frac12))$ for odd and even degree respectively, while the Stirling numbers are the coefficients of $\prod_{j=1}^k(x-j)$. I would expect corresponding integral families (or sums involving generalized harmonic numbers) to exist, but haven't encountered yet. The only other polynomials with a similar function which I am aware of ... (cont'd)

Comment: ... are the [Mittag-Leffler polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_polynomials#Closed_forms_of_integral_families). BTW you can see that for those, the arguments of the zetas are able to "progress in both directions", comparing examples #1 and #4/5. So there should be chances that for the polynomials $\prod_{j=1}^k(x-j)$ (i.e. Stirling) there is also a positive answer. Maybe not with the zetas directly, but some multiplicator as for the $tanh^n/x^m$.

Comment: @PietroMajer No more mystery about the general form of $I_{n,m}$. It's all [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_polynomials#Closed_forms_of_integral_families).

Comment: @Wolfgang Very interesting, thank you. Is this perhaps something you'd be interested working on with me? For instance, we could start be listing some possible functions and closed form evaluations of integrals of integer powers of them, to try to find likely candidates that amound to the Stirling-zeta values

Comment: @MaxMuller Of course. As you may imagine, I have already been looking at this kind of integrals, and I am even mulling about introducing a tag like "umbral-closed-form-zeta" to easily identify them. Also on https://math.stackexchange.com, which tends to have more integrals of this kind than https://mathoverflow.net.

Comment: @Wolfgang Ah yes, such a tag might indeed be useful. If you'd like to collaborate on this, it might be wise to coordinate which integrals may be worthwhile to consider, and exchange ideas. You can contact me via maxmuller100 [at] gmail [dot] com. I am for instance interested in how you obtain conjectures for closed forms of integrals - I now try them via wolfram alpha and then I put the digits in OEIS, but I suspect there's a faster method through some kind of symbolic computation software. If we work together, we might be more efficient and we might be able to find the Stirling-zeta values

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Following the suggestion I made in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/271526/is-there-a-closed-form-for-int-0-infty-frac-tanh3xx2dx#comment672036_271526), the integral can be rewritten as the contour integral
$$
  I_{3,2} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint \frac{\operatorname{tanh}^3 z}{z^2} \log(-z) \, dz ,
$$
where the clockwise contour tightly encircles the positive real axis, which coincides with the branch cut of the logarithm. The reason that this integral is equivalent is because the branch jump across the real line of $\frac{1}{2\pi i} \log(-z)$ is precisely $1$.

The integrand has poles at all $z=\pm i\pi(k+\frac{1}{2})$, $k=0,1,2,\ldots$. Evaluating the residues we find
\begin{align*}
  I_{3,2}
  &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{8\log\pi(k+\frac{1}{2})}{\pi^2 (2k+1)^2} - \frac{96 \log\pi(k+\frac{1}{2})-80}{\pi^4 (2k+1)^4} \\
  &= \frac{5}{6} - \gamma - \frac{19 \log 2}{15} + 12 \log A - \log\pi + \frac{90 \zeta'(4)}{\pi^4} \\
  &= 1.1547853133231762640590704519415261475352370924508924890\ldots
\end{align*}
The last two lines can be checked with [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B8+(Log%5B2*k%2B1%5D%2BLog%5BPi%2F2%5D)%2FPi%5E2%2F(2*k%2B1)%5E2-(96+(Log%5B2*k%2B1%5D%2BLog%5BPi%2F2%5D)-80)%2FPi%5E4%2F(2*k%2B1)%5E4,%7Bk,0,Infinity%7D%5D), where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant), and $A$ is the [Glaisher constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaisher%E2%80%93Kinkelin_constant).

***Edit:** Using $\gamma =12\,\log(A)-\log(2\pi)+\frac{6}{\pi^2}\,\zeta'(2)$, this can be simplified to
$$I_{3,2}=\frac{5}{6}  - \frac{4\log 2}{15}   -\frac{6\zeta'(2)}{\pi^2}+ \frac{90 \zeta'(4)}{\pi^4},$$ that is
$$\boxed{I_{3,2}=\frac{5}{6}  - \frac{4\log 2}{15}   -\frac{\zeta'(2)}{\zeta(2)}+ \frac{\zeta'(4)}{\zeta(4)}}.
 $$ And this form may hint to the existence of similar closed forms for other integrals* $I_{n,m}$ with $n+m$ odd.

***Edit:*** Indeed... Numerically, it looks like e.g.
$$ I(5,2)=\frac1{3}\Bigl(\frac{8}{5}-\frac{44}{63}\log2-3\frac{\zeta'(2)}{\zeta(2)} +5 \frac{\zeta'(4)}{\zeta(4)}-2\frac{\zeta'(6)}{\zeta(6)} \Bigr)$$
$$ I(7,2)=\frac1{45}\Bigl(\frac{7943}{420}-\frac{428}{45}\log2- 45\frac{\zeta'(2)}{\zeta(2)}+ 98\frac{\zeta'(4)}{\zeta(4)}- 70\frac{\zeta'(6)}{\zeta(6)}+ 17\frac{\zeta'(8)}{\zeta(8)}\Bigr)$$
$$ I(9,2)=\frac1{315}\Bigl(\frac{71077}{630}-\frac{10196}{165}\log2- 315\frac{\zeta'(2)}{\zeta(2)}+ 818\frac{\zeta'(4)}{\zeta(4)}- 798\frac{\zeta'(6)}{\zeta(6)}+ 357\frac{\zeta'(8)}{\zeta(8)}- 62\frac{\zeta'(10)}{\zeta(10)}\Bigr)$$
$$I(11,2)=\frac1{14175}\Bigl(\frac{2230796}{495}-\frac{10719068}{4095}\log2- 14175\frac{\zeta'(2)}{\zeta(2)}+ 41877\frac{\zeta'(4)}{\zeta(4)}- 50270\frac{\zeta'(6)}{\zeta(6)}+ 31416\frac{\zeta'(8)}{\zeta(8)}- 10230\frac{\zeta'(10)}{\zeta(10)}+1382\frac{\zeta'(12)}{\zeta(12)}\Bigr)$$
$$I(13,2)=\frac1{467775}\Bigl(\frac{270932553}{2002}-\frac{25865068}{315}\log2- 467775\frac{\zeta'(2)}{\zeta(2)}+ 1528371\frac{\zeta'(4)}{\zeta(4)}- 2137564\frac{\zeta'(6)}{\zeta(6)}+ 1672528\frac{\zeta'(8)}{\zeta(8)}- 771342\frac{\zeta'(10)}{\zeta(10)}+197626\frac{\zeta'(12) }{\zeta(12)}-21844\frac{\zeta'(14) }{\zeta(14)}\Bigr)$$

Here the initial denominators are chosen as the least common denominators of the $\frac{\zeta'(2k)}{\zeta(2k)}$ terms, such that inside the big parentheses, we have integer coefficients here. It turns out that the sequence of those denominators, viz. $1, 3, 45, 315, 14175, 467775$, coincides up to signs with [A117972](https://oeis.org/A117972), the numerators of the rational numbers $\frac{\pi^{2n}\;\zeta'(-2n)}{\zeta(2n+1)}$.

Moreover, note that the coefficients of the $\frac{\zeta'(2k)}{\zeta(2k)}$ have alternating signs and always sum to 0, meaning that the closed forms can be decomposed into terms $\frac{\zeta'(2k)}{\zeta(2k)}-\frac{\zeta'(2k-2)}{\zeta(2k-2)}$, which are thus "exponential periods".

Further, the numerators of the $\frac{\zeta'(2n)}{\zeta(2n)}$ term of $I_{2n-1,2}$, viz. $1, -2, 17, -62, 1382, -21844$, coincide with [A002430](https://oeis.org/A002430), the numerators of the Taylor series for $\tanh(x)$, which are also closely related to the rational values $\zeta(1-2n)$. All this seems rather interesting.

Comment: Now that is cute. Thank you very much!

Comment: I wonder whether this sets a record for largest number of important constants in a single formula.

Comment: Notice that both the **Glaisher-Kinkelin** and **Euler-Mascheroni** constants can be rewritten in terms of the [Riemann $\zeta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) as $\gamma=\dfrac{\zeta(1^+)+\zeta(1^-)}2~$ and $~12\ln A=1-12~\zeta'(-1).$

Comment: @GerryMyerson Not exactly a record anymore. :) I wonder how often "verbose" closed forms of this kind of integrals (more frequent on math.se) can indeed be simplified!

Comment: And for the record [not in @GerryMyerson 's sense, though :) ], we have: $$I(11,2)=\frac1{14175}\Bigl(\frac{2230796}{495}-\frac{10719068}{4095}\log2- 14175\frac{\zeta'(2)}{\zeta(2)}+ 41877\frac{\zeta'(4)}{\zeta(4)}- 50270\frac{\zeta'(6)}{\zeta(6)}+ 31416\frac{\zeta'(8)}{\zeta(8)}- 10230\frac{\zeta'(10)}{\zeta(10)}+1382\frac{\zeta'(12)}{\zeta(12)}\Bigr)$$

Answer (score 20):

Rewrite the integrand and apply Taylor expansion to $\frac1{(1+e^{-2x})^3}$ so that
$$\frac{\tanh^3x}{x^2}=\sum_{j\geq0}(-1)^j\binom{j+2}2
\frac{(1-e^{-2x})^3}{x^2}\binom{j+2}2e^{-2jx}.$$
Integrate term-wise to get (after some regrouping)
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\tanh^3x}{x^2}\,dx=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(-1)^k(8k^3+4k)\log k.$$
Perhaps there is some hope in view of what I see as
$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(-1)^k\log k=\log\sqrt{\frac2{\pi}};$$
which is a Wallis-type formula
$$\frac23\cdot\frac45\cdot\frac67\cdots\frac{2k}{2k+1}\cdots=\sqrt{\frac2{\pi}}.$$

**UPDATE.** Using a divergent series approach on $\sum_k(-1)^kk^c$ and Will Sawin's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/271526/is-there-a-closed-form-for-int-0-infty-frac-tanh3xx2dx#comment672170_271569), we can complete the solution as follows. Start with $\sum_{k\geq1}(-1)^kk^c=\zeta(-c)(2^{c+1}-1)$ to get the derivate
$$\sum_{k\geq2}(-1)^ck^c\log k=-\zeta'(-c)(2^{c+1}-1)+\zeta(-c)2^{c+1}\log2.$$
Now, apply the following facts: $\zeta(-1)=-\frac1{12},\, \zeta'(-1)=\frac1{12}-\log A,\, \zeta(-3)=\frac1{120}$ and
$$\zeta'(-3)=\frac1{120}\log(2\pi)-\frac{11}{720}+\frac1{120}\gamma-\frac{3\zeta'(4)}{4\pi^4}.$$
Next, put all these together and simplify
\begin{align}\sum_{k\geq0}(-1)^k(8k^3+4k)\log k
&=[-120\zeta'(-3)+128\zeta(-3)\log 2]+[-12\zeta'(-1)+16\zeta(-1)\log 2] \\
&=\frac56-\gamma-\log\pi-\frac{19}{15}\log2+12\log A+\frac{\zeta'(4)}{\zeta(4)}.
\end{align}

Comment: One may start by finding a divergent series formula for $\sum_{k\geq2}(-1)^kk^c$ for a range of values of $c$ real. Take derivative to get $\sum_k(-1)^kk^c\log k$ and then put $c=1$.

Comment: $\sum_k (-1)^k k^c$ is $\left( \sum_k k^c \right) (-1 + 2^{1+c} )$ and the first term is of course $\zeta(-c)$.  This is surely related to the appearance of the derivative of $\zeta$ in Igor's formula.

Comment: This is super, Ramanujan style!

Comment: Indeed very cute, as well as Igor  Khavkine's approach above.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine's [approach](https://mathoverflow.net/a/271633) mentioned above.